# Issue with PHP trim

Tags: php, asterisk, trim

I have banged my head for the past 4 hours and I cant understand why my second trim is creating duplicates.
This code with no trim works well and produces what I want.

```
<h1>Offline Phones</h1>
<?php

// Query For All Peers
exec("/usr/sbin/asterisk -r -x 'sip show peers'", $response);

foreach($response as $line) {


  $offline = $line;

    if (strpos($offline, "UNKNOWN")>0) {
    print "<span style='color:red;'>$offline</span><br>";  
    }
}
?>

<h1>Online Phones</h1>
<?php

// Query For All Peers
exec("/usr/sbin/asterisk -r -x 'sip show peers'", $responses);

foreach($responses as $lines) {
$online = $lines;


    if (strpos($online, "OK")>0) {

    print "<span style='color:green;'>$online</span><br>";   
    }
}
?>
```

The above code produces:
Offline Phones

302 (Unspecified) D N A 0 UNKNOWN
303 (Unspecified) D N A 0 UNKNOWN
304 (Unspecified) D N A 0 UNKNOWN
305 (Unspecified) D N A 0 UNKNOWN
306 (Unspecified) D N A 0 UNKNOWN
Online Phones

301/301 192.168.1.96 D N A 45009 OK (6 ms)
307/307 192.168.1.112 D N A 50175 OK (5 ms)

BUT when I add trims (See Code below) to both querys the second query has duplicate items.

```
<h1>Offline Phones</h1>
<?php

// Query For All Peers
exec("/usr/sbin/asterisk -r -x 'sip show peers'", $response);

foreach($response as $line) {


  $offline = $line;

    if (strpos($offline, "UNKNOWN")>0)
    $clean_offline = trim($offline, '(Unspecified) D N A 0 UNKNOWN');
    {
    echo "<span style='color:red;'>$clean_offline</span><br>";  
    }
}



// Query For All Peers
exec("/usr/sbin/asterisk -r -x 'sip show peers'", $responses);

foreach($responses as $lines) {

   $online = $lines;


    if (strpos($online, "OK")>0) 

    $clean_online = trim($online);
    {
    echo "<span style='color:green;'>$clean_online</span><br>";   
    }
}
?>
```

This code produces duplicates as shown in the output below. You will notice I don't even have a trim rule added.

302
303
304
305
306
306
306

301/301 192.168.1.96 D N A 45009 OK (5 ms)
301/301 192.168.1.96 D N A 45009 OK (5 ms)
301/301 192.168.1.96 D N A 45009 OK (5 ms)
301/301 192.168.1.96 D N A 45009 OK (5 ms)
301/301 192.168.1.96 D N A 45009 OK (5 ms)
301/301 192.168.1.96 D N A 45009 OK (5 ms)
307/307 192.168.1.112 D N A 50175 OK (5 ms)
307/307 192.168.1.112 D N A 50175 OK (5 ms)

... There should only be 301/301 192.168.1.96 D N A 45009 OK (5 ms) & 307/307 192.168.1.112 D N A 50175 OK (5 ms) here. Can anyone show me where i have went wrong?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Perhaps reading ___exactly___ what trim() does in the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) would help understand, paying particular attention to the second argument... it's called $charlist for a reason

Comment: Also, when performing things inside a loop, don't be suprised when they happen more than once.

Comment: Sorry Folks, I'm no a engineer.. that's why I'm here seeking help. When you say a loop; what do you mean? Mark the doc you have sent is what I initially used to help trim.

Comment: Don't use trim for that, use str_replace and replace that string to an empty one. Then after that use trim to get rid of control characters

Answer (score 2):

You missed the `{}` brackets. All the code that you want run after the `if` should be contained there. so

```
if (strpos($offline, "UNKNOWN")>0)
$clean_offline = trim($offline, '(Unspecified) D N A 0 UNKNOWN');
{
echo "<span style='color:red;'>$clean_offline</span><br>";  
}
```

should be

```
if (strpos($offline, "UNKNOWN")>0)
{
  $clean_offline = trim($offline, '(Unspecified) D N A 0 UNKNOWN');
  {
    echo "<span style='color:red;'>$clean_offline</span><br>";  
  }
}
```

And the same with the next code block

```
if (strpos($online, "OK")>0) 

$clean_online = trim($online);
{
echo "<span style='color:green;'>$clean_online</span><br>";   
}
```

should be

```
if (strpos($online, "OK")>0) 
{
   $clean_online = trim($online);
   {
      echo "<span style='color:green;'>$clean_online</span><br>";   
   }
}
```

It's not an issue with `trim()`, rather the `strpos` condition which assigns `$online` to `$clean_online`, is only evaluated once and is used on all subsequent iterations.

Comment: +1 Good catch, but you are missing that `trim` does not work like that in the first block; it does not cut off a string, but individual characters. That may now lead - by accident - to the same result the OP intented, but it will not automatically, it is likely to cut off way more than anticipated.

Comment: @jeroen not sure where I addressed that point. His question was based on a mistaken premise. It's not the `trim` which is creating duplicates, rather a malformed `if` block.

Comment: It's worth mentioning as it would make your answer better and to avoid a follow-up comment like `...now I am missing entries instead of having duplicates...` when whole lines get trimmed away :-)

Answer (score 0):

This does not look correct:

```
foreach($response as $line) {

  $offline = $line;

    if (strpos($offline, "UNKNOWN")>0)
    $clean_offline = trim($offline, '(Unspecified) D N A 0 UNKNOWN');
    {
    echo "<span style='color:red;'>$clean_offline</span><br>";  
    }
}
```

It should look like this:

```
foreach($response as $line)
{
    // strpos returns a position if exists, ZERO is valid
    // you get boolean false if it does not exist
    if(strpos($line, "UNKNOWN"))
    {
        echo "<span style='color:red;'>".trim($line, '(Unspecified) D N A 0 UNKNOWN')"</span><br>";     
    }
    elseif(strpos($online, "OK"))
    {
        echo "<span style='color:green;'>".trim($line)."</span><br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorted.. Thanks to all you gentlemen!